# Как в методе с возвращаемым значением выйти из цикла правильно

Tags: c#

Всех приветствую, вот сделал метод, он  читает файл по частям, на вход метода подаем поток, возвращает метод переменную количества блоков, и также возвращает структуру KeyValuePair
Не могу сообразить, как выйти правильно  из метода с помощью return. Заранее всем спасибо.

```
        public static KeyValuePair<int, byte[]> Read_Blok(Stream stream,out int count_blok)
    {



       int size = 1024 * 1024;
       int count_part = (int) (stream.Length /size );// количество частей
       int sizeLastPart = count_part - 1; // размер последней части
       byte[] buffer = new byte[size]; // размер буффера
       count_blok = 0;
       int count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count_part; i++)
        {

            if (i == count_part - 1) // когда достигаем последней части, последняя часть блока может быть меньше чем заданный буфер
            {
                buffer = new byte[sizeLastPart];
                count=stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                count_blok = count_blok + 1;
                return new KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>(count_blok,buffer);

            }
            else
            {
                count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                count_blok = count_blok + 1;
                return new KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>(count_blok,buffer);
                stream.Position = i * buffer.Length;// сдвигаем позицию в потоке


            }


        }


    }
```

Comment: а такой манёвр не актуален здесь - 'return;'

Comment: В блоке else выйти нужно?

Comment: @AquaGF Вот как раз я и думаю, как мне правильно вернуться из метода со значением KeyValuePair<int, byte[]> и со значением переменной. То есть как мне без return выйти.

Comment: а без return вы никак не выйдите. Метод имеет возращаемый тип а в ином случае проект даже не скомпилируется - ошибка не все ветви кода возвращают значение. Для этого есть приём с использованием просто return принудительный выход из цикла. Насколько я понял то что вам и нужно

Comment: @AquaGF да это вы имеете ввиду break; ?

Comment: Да, извините, break  попробуй

Comment: Вы плохо описали, что должен вернуть этот метод.

Comment: KeyValuePair<int,byte[]>?

Comment: @Igor да я хочу вернуть из метода ода пару Ключ значение KeyValuePair<int,byte[]> затем эту пару ключ значение  положу в очередь

Comment: Суть в том что вы не можете использовать какие либо дейсвия после ключевого слова return как у вас в блоке else

Comment: Недостижимый код

Comment: @AquaGF за пределами метода я могу положить это дело в очередь, или как вариант тогда мне проще из метода возвращаться сразу очередь  из пар ключ-значение.

Comment: Тогда в коде неправильно то, что Вы каждый раз начинаете цикл с начала.

Comment: Вычисление `count_part` тоже неправильно.

Comment: Дописываю ответ

Comment: @Igor Да тогда получается путаница,я сейчас об этом подумал, тогда мне проще вернуть сразу всю очередь из ключей-значений, только встает другой вопрос,что мне делать если файл слишком большой и тогда очередь может в оперативку не влезть. А про  count_part, вы имеете ввиду, что  по длиннее потока не верно вычислять? по сути это же тот же размер файла, или тут явно нужно с размером файла работать?

Comment: Идея с возвращением кусков нормальная, только исполнение - не очень. Подождем ответ от @AquaGF.

Comment: Не ответ больше решение проблемы с недостижимым кодом. Режет глаз немного. Я чесно говоря в потоках не силён но сути изменить не должно

Comment: @Igor Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так, я про вашу реплику, что я каждый раз цикл начинаю сначала, и сейчас получается что, метод отработал и он все время возвращает последнюю часть

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Сейчас.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо большое жду, сейчас в отладчике смотрю по шагам, из else vметод не выходит, и номинально только последняя часть выходит и ее я и добавляю в очередь, а как мне тогда организовать работу метода,чтобы из него каждую итерацию выходил блок,то есть ключ значение

Comment: @Igor Вижу код, интересно очень, а пожалуйста объясните логику вот тут new byte[System.Math.Min(SIZE_BLOCK, stream.Length - stream.Position)];

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch добавил объяснение в ответ.

Comment: @Igor Да все отлично работает, все лаконично, скажите пожалуйста ,а вот сейчас я пишу,вернее переделываю методы компрессии и декомпрессии, с учетом? что мне нужно будет делать это (сжимать и разжимать) в отдельных потоках, как можно организовать метод сжатия, в MemoryStream, в обычном методе сжатия, этот поток открывается в самом методе, лучше наверное открыть один поток и несколькими методами сжимать блоки? Или все таки лучше в самом методе каждый раз открывать MemoryStream. И еще вопрос. как мне лучше оперировать индексами блоков?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>> Read_Block(Stream stream)
{
  const int SIZE_BLOCK = 1024 * 1024; // one megabyte

  int index = 0;
  while (stream.Position < stream.Length)
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[System.Math.Min(SIZE_BLOCK, stream.Length - stream.Position)];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    yield return new KeyValuePair<int, byte[]>(index++, buffer);
  }
}

public static void Test()
{
  using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream("file name", FileMode.Open))
  {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, byte[]> block in Read_Block(fStream))
    {
      // process block.Value
    }
  }
}
```

Строчка

```
... = new byte[System.Math.Min(SIZE_BLOCK, stream.Length - stream.Position)];
```

выделяет память под массив в один мегабайт или, если до конца потока осталось меньше, в столько байт, сколько осталось до конца потока.

Comment: Понял, это тоже самое что у меня в if проверяется, но короче и правильнее

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю что не так с вычислением count_part но вот так код не должен изменить свою актуальность и функционал, а @Igor правит ответ с новым вычислением переменной.

```
public static KeyValuePair<int, byte[]> Read_Blok(Stream stream, out int count_blok)
    {
        int size = 1024 * 1024;
        int count_part = (int)(stream.Length / size);// количество частей
        int sizeLastPart = count_part - 1; // размер последней части
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size]; // размер буффера
        count_blok = 0;
        int count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count_part; i++)
        {
            if (i == count_part - 1) // когда достигаем последней части, последняя часть блока может быть меньше чем заданный буфер
            {
                buffer = new byte[sizeLastPart];
                count = stream.Read (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                count_blok = count_blok + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                count = stream.Read (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                count_blok = count_blok + 1;
                stream.Position = i * buffer.Length;// сдвигаем позицию в потоке
            }
        }
        return new KeyValuePair<int, byte[]> (count_blok, buffer);

    }
```